# Codeigniter multiple parameter on update

Tags: codeigniter

I am copying this code in Codeigniter official docs, but I don't know why this will throw an error

```
 public function acceptChangeRequest($id,$data1,$accept) {
    $data = array(
        'status' => $accept,
        'approve_by' => $data1,
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('change_request',$data);
    //return true;
}
```

> Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

UPDATE `change_request` SET `status` = 'Y', `approve_by` = Array WHERE `id` = '22'

It sounds wierd since this code works in my other function. Any idea?

Comment: public function acceptChangeRequest($id,$data1,$accept)                                            print_r($data1) check what is coming in data 1 it coming an array thats way it throws the error

Comment: Seems like `$data1` is an array. Debug it with `var_dump($data1);exit;` at the beginning of the method to see what is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Read The Documentation Clearly 
[Read About Update Records In Codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Here IS Demo Function For You

```
public function updateBasic($data,$user_id){

        $userData=array(
            'marital_status'=>$data['marital_status'],
            'country'=>$data['stateofresidence'],
            'city'=>$data['city'],
            'caste'=>$data['caste'],
            'residential_status'=>$data['residencystatus']
        );
        $this->db->WHERE('user_id',$user_id)->update('basic_profile',$userData);
        return true;
    }
```

You Must Check Through Print_r();what Is coming To your Function In Your Case $data1 Is Coming In the From OF array You Must Extract The Array To Update The Record

Answer (score 0):

Use this function in your model to update the record.

```
public function acceptChangeRequest($where, $table, $data){
    $this->db->where($where);
    $this->db->update($table, $data);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

use this code in your controller.

```
  $where = array('id'=>$id);

  $data = array(
     'status' => $accept,
     'approve_by' => $data1,
  );
  $this->User_model->update($where,'table_name',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

What is in your `$data1` variable? I can see that it's an array, and that is the problem.

If your `$data1` stores indexes like in your table's row, than this is the possible solution for you:

```
public function acceptChangeRequest($id,$data1,$accept) {
    $data1["status"] = $accept;

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('change_request', $data1);

    return true;
}
```

But if your `$data1` variable stores only the *approve_by* information, than your possible solution is:

```
public function acceptChangeRequest($id,$data1,$accept) {
    $data = array(
        'status' => $accept,
        'approve_by' => $data1["approve_by"]
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('change_request', $data);

    return true;
}
```

First of all, you need to know what you expect from `$data1`, than you can move forward to the solution.

You can see your `$data1` variable in your Controller's function:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($data1);
print "<pre>";

die();
```